# Application.Screenupdating and Windows 10

Tags: excel, vba

I’m rewording my original question in an attempt to clarify things.

I write code for a number of clients who are still running Windows XP as their OS.

One of the tests I do before shipping out any code is to “drag” any forms that are displayed, to make sure there’s no drag trail, thus getting a quick visual confirmation that ScreenUpdating is set to True.

This worked well with Windows XP and earlier OS’s, and also with Windows 7 if using non-Aero themes.

But with Windows 10 I do NOT get a drag trail, no matter what ScreenUpdating is set to.  Consequently I do not have the quick visual test I had before upgrading to Win 10.

If you run this snippet of code on Windows 10 you will not see a drag trail like you do on earlier OS versions.

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Yes, I can work around this issue, but it would be somewhat easier if I didn’t have to.

So my question: is there any setting in Windows 10 that turns this “feature” off?

Comment: Why are you turning off screen updating in the first place just to show a form?

Comment: Because the client objects to to seeing the trail if/when he moves the form, which is to be expected.

Comment: You're seeing a "trail" **because** `ScreenUpdating` is turned off (Excel doesn't repaint anymore). Rule of thumb, you NEVER want `ScreenUpdating` turned off when you're showing a UI (be it a form, a `StatusBar` message, a `MsgBox`, ...). Remove that `ScreenUpdating` toggle, it has no business being there. That said, not sure what the question is.

Comment: @braX, I misspoke in my comment, I turn do screen updating ON to show a form.  The point I'm trying to make is if turning screen updating gets missed, it won't be apparent until it's run under an older os, such as Win XP

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I'm fully aware of that, I'm not trying to turn off screen updating before displaying a form, see my comment to braX.  I thought my question was stated clearly, apparently that's not the case.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] anytime. What do you mean with "if screen updating gets missed"?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon So say I've missed a line when writing my code, and forgotten to turn screen updating ON before displaying a form.  Then when I'm testing my code under Win 10, I'll never notice it, as there won't be any drag trails,  But the client will as soon as he runs it on his Win XP system.  The workaround for this in Win 7 was to NOT use aero themes.  But as I explained, I can't find a similar solution with Win 10.

Comment: Make a generic `Presenter` class whose job is to display a form - and make that method ensure screen updating is on before it pops the form... and then resets it to what it was when the form is closed. Now you have to remember to do `With New FooPresenter` and invoke, say, some `.ShowDialog` method, and you know all is taken care of if you see `With New FooPresenter` somewhere.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, Actually I already do run something like you're suggesting when displaying a form.  What I was hoping for was a visual confirmation that all was well, like I was able to do in Win 7 and previous os's, with a simple drag on the form.  It's starting to look like maybe it's not possible anymore.  Thanks for your comments.